# Creating Unique identifier in Excel that links the same record on different deliveries

Tags: excel, unique

I need to create an unique ID that will identify each business, so I can see on each delivery if they were added, removed or updated. Some background below:

- I have a client who will make deliveries of business to be mapped in CSV format
- The client will every quarter deliver a new file, which probably will
  not be exactly the same data, it may contain addition, removals,
  updates.
- I don't want to do normalization in the data, because I want to
  compare each raw delivery to see what has changed from one delivery
  to the other.
- The files can contain thousands or just a few records
- It will be difficult to create uniqueness only on field concatenation, because the record can change a lot, of just a little.
- The order of the business can change during deliveries (the first one can be in the middle or in the bottom)

I think there is no way to create uniqueness, can someone help me here?

Example of data to be delivered:

[image]

Comment: So what have you tried to create a unique ID?  Have you thought about simple uniqueness, like a sequence number? Are you limited to formulas, or are you able to use VBA?

Comment: I think it is okay to use VBA, although I'm not good at it. I tried to create it based on concatenation of zipcode and country but it didn't work, in the other delivery the same record had only a space between the zipcodes which in my algorism ended in an Addition (of the new business) and Removal (of the old business). But I mainly tried on concatenations...different concatenations...but it didn't work.

Comment: Obviously, if you have two people from the same country and zip code, it's going to fail.  What you can do is set up a counter on a sheet that you hide away; you can give it a name, something like `sequenceNumber`.  On creation of a new row, a particular cell must be given the current ID from `sequenceNumber`, then `sequenceNumber` is incremented by one.  Have a go, yourself, first, and see what you can come up with - the best way to learn is by trying it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, but I forgot to mention that the provider gives me CSV files, which I later translate them into excel format. I'll add this information in the question. I guess there is no way to create this UniqueIDs....I will check if I can change the provider's process to have some kind of uniqueIDs.

Comment: Yes - put a sanitised sample of the CSV files; this will make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Apologies for not getting back to you. It would appear that the most obvious primary key you have here is to use the long and lat together for your uniqueness; unless the businesses are on top of each other, then there shouldn't be an issue. If this is a problem, then include the business name, also.